Suggestion for better Email notification software or App (Budget friendly) that can be integrated with Salesforce
We need to send mass emails which might cross the limit (5000 for external email addresses per day). I am not aware of the options which help us overcome this limit. Kindly suggest.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

We don't have problem as of now as we are not hitting daily email limit of salesforce (I.e 5000 for external email addresses), I am asking for suggestion, if there are any functionality, apps or tools that can be integrated wit salesforce that allow us increase the 5000 limit

You should check on AppExchange and search the web to find the app that meets your requirements.

There is a maximum of 5,000 emails that can be sent within 24 hours. This maximum is only available if you have Salesforce Unlimited Edition.
From the salesforce docs:
Using the API or Apex, you can send single emails to a maximum of 5,000 external email addresses per day based on Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).
If they are marketing emails, and you want to get into marketing automation, then consider using Marketing Cloud, or Pardot.
If you just want to send lots of emails simply and relatively cheaply, you will need to make callouts to a specialist email delivery service. You can use SendGrid and Amazon SES for these purposes.
